# phpunit-selenium 's keys() not working for safari webdriver

Tags: selenium, phpunit, automated-tests, safaridriver

I am struggling to find any solution to run keys() selenium function on safari webdriver. It is working fine for Firefox, Chrome and IE.

I have gone through below solutions but did not found any working

[Selenium webdriver on Safari: Keys.ENTER not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994399/selenium-webdriver-on-safari-keys-enter-not-working)

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6666

[Selenium sendKeys() different behaviour for Chrome, Firefox and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547459/selenium-sendkeys-different-behaviour-for-chrome-firefox-and-safari)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solution
SendKeys() works with latest selenium server version (3.5.3) http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/